# OSX VIM clipboard support

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

Does anyone here know why on OSX, clipboard is not supported in VIM editor? and what is the impact of compile from source to replace the existing binary?

Thanks,

Comment: The clipboard works fine for me in MacVim 7.3 on OSX 10.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `set cb=unnamed` to your .vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got an answer. Looking a my vim build, the clipboard module is not enabled. That's the reason why I try *p doesn't work for me.

So either I've to recompile VIM to enable clipboard support or MacVIM as alternative.

There is also another solution which is to use pbcopy/pbpaste. It's even better to map keystroke to this command line.

Dara kok

Answer (score 0):

Try the * register.
In insert mode, type Ctrl-R *
Or in normal mode, type "*p to put something from the OS (global) clipboard.
Similarly "*y to yank something to the global clipboard.

fake-clip.vim plugin is useful in many environments where the * register is not implemented. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098

Answer (score 0):

add it to .vimrc (OSX10.8.5 VIM7.3)

```
vmap "+y :w !pbcopy<CR><CR> 
nmap "+p :r !pbpaste<CR><CR>
```